# What should I look for in Alex apartments?

Tags: prey

In Prey (2017), there is side quest

> to escape Talos-1 station, given by operator December.

Eventually, quest leads you to apartments of Alex Yu in living quarters section of station, to find key, which is hidden "on the data tower, near chair", so quest mark is displayed on Alex Yu apartments.

I've searched whole apartments several times, but I have no idea, what I should look for, and I can't find anything. So, what should I look for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, found it. It's

> under globe near bed.